# Imagick Memory & CPU limits

Tags: php, cpu-usage, imagick

I am using Imagick latest version & PHP 5.3. When I try to create a thumbnail for images (code below), the script uses too much CPU. How can I set limits on resource consumption on Imagick?

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage($this->tmp_file);
$thumb->thumbnailImage(200, null);
$thumb->writeImage($this->thumb_file);
$thumb->destroy();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? If you are trying to create a thumbnail each time a user visits the page you are going to create a very heavy load on the CPU very quickly. You can solve this by only generating the image once and saving it to a thumbnail directory.

You can also set PHP to have a specific memory limit using the PHP.ini or ini_set commands. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

I do not think you can specifically set a memory limit in imagemagick unless you can set the command line parameters yourself (Last answer [here](http://drupal.org/node/985784))

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can change Imagick's limits using [`setResourceLimit`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresourcelimit.php):

```
Imagick::setResourceLimit( $type, $limit );
```

Available type constants:

```
Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA
Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK
Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_FILE
Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP
Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY
```

You can see what one of the limits is currently using [`getResourceLimit`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getresourcelimit.php), using the same constants listed above:

```
Imagick::getResourceLimit( $type )
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Advice**

A. Take Advantage of Cache

B. Don't generate Thumb all the time

C. Use a Job Queing System such as `Gearman` or `beanstalkd` to generate thumbs so that you don't have to do it instantly

Example only generate thumb when the original file has been modified

```
$file = "a.jpg" ;
$thumbFile = "a.thumb.jpg" ;
$createThumb = true;
if(is_file($thumbFile))
{
    if((filemtime($file) - 10) < filemtime($thumbFile));
    {
        $createThumb = false;
    }
}


if($createThumb === true)
{
    $thumb = new Imagick();
    $thumb->readImage($file);
    $thumb->thumbnailImage(50, null);
    $thumb->writeImage($thumbFile);
    $thumb->destroy();
}
```